# f:param not working when used with trinidad 2

Tags: jsf-2, trinidad

I am using JSF 2 Trinidad 2(MyFaces) and trying to use f:param in a command button

```
<tr:commandButton text="Submit" action={backingBean.actionSubmit}>
<f:param name="isSubmit" value="Yes" />
</tr:commandButton>
```

Basically I am trying to pass the param value for submit button and only perform the validation if a Submit button is clicked adding the condition to the required attribute for input elements to check for the submit button.

Is there a way to identify a particular button click in JSF2/Trinidad2 so that I can check for that button click in the validation method.

Comment: Baluc - Thank you for all your responses ..do you know if I can try anything else to achieve this I am trying to skip the validation on a specific button click

Answer (score 0):

I am using JSF 1.2 but I think it works in JSF 2.0 the same way.

For your commandButton use an actionListener instead of action.

```
<tr:commandButton text="Submit" actionListener={backingBean.actionSubmit}>
```

Within your bean you can get the id of your button:

```
public void actionSubmit(ActionEvent event)
{
   event.getComponent().getId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider to use [`<tr:setActionListener/>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/tagdoc/tr_setActionListener.html). In your case you could use something like:

```
<tr:commandButton text="Submit" action="#{backingBean.actionSubmit}">
  <tr:setActionListener from="submit" to="#{backingBean.pressedButton}" />
</tr:commandButton>
```

Basically you use it to copy an object from the `from` attribute to the `to` attribute. Note that you could use EL in the `from` attribute as well (`#{someBean.someObject}`).

In you backing bean you need to add a `String` member called `pressedButton` (with getter and setter). Now you can use the following code in your `actionSubmit`

```
if ("submit".equals(pressedButton))
{
  System.out.println("You pressed 'sumbit'");
}
```